# Need Design Advise C++: Want to implement a threaded queue for other threads to pass data

Tags: c++, visual-studio, multithreading

I've not done any thread programming before, so i wanted to ask you guys for some design suggestions and also about stuffs i should be aware of about thread programming.

**Environment:** MFC/C++, VS2005
**Problem:** I have a vendor library running threads to poll data and receive reports from devices. Number of threads can reach 100+ depending on the number of devices. Everytime a thread receives data, it needs to call a sequence of functions(from a vendor SDK, not thread safe) to update values on the GUI.

**Solution??:** My friend suggested me to use a thread with a built in queue to synchronize updating data to the GUI. Whenever the other threads receives data, it'll add an entry to the queue in this thread. This thread will then call the sequence of functions until the queue is empty and wait for new entries.

I did some reading on _beginthreadex(), _endthreadex(), boost::thread, semaphore and mutex concept. How do you think i should implement this? What pitfalls i should be aware of?
Please advise.

Comment: Im confused: Is the vendor library creating the threads? or responsible for the GUI? When data happens on one of these threads, the vendor library notifies you how? Calling a callback function? I mean: how can the vendor library both create multiple threads, and be "not thread safe" ?

Comment: sorry bout that.. i should have been more clear in the beginning. There are two vendor libraries involved. LibVen A handles the GUI and LibVen B handles the communication to the devices via threads. Functions in LibVen A are not thread safe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to check out intel TBB,

http://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/files/documentation/a00129.html seems to possibly do exactly what you want.

Comment: hi JH, i just checked it out. It definitely looks exactly what i'm looking for and it looks very simple to use. I'll try it out and let you know how it goes.. thanks

Answer (score 2):

I've posted some code in [a previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3054701/is-there-a-set-of-win32-api-functions-to-manage-synchronized-queues/3054795#3054795) that should be usable. Though some of the comments there mention I/O Completion ports, they don't really apply to your case. Microsoft's attempt at roughly the same is the SList, but (IMO) this has some pretty serious problems, starting with (IMO) a fatally flawed design (or, if not fatally flawed, at least totally unsuited to your purposes -- and most others, anyway) and then adding some annoyances. The fatal flaw is that it's really designed to act as a stack instead of a queue<sup>1</sup>. This is almost certainly dead wrong for your application. For annoyances, [`QueryDepthSlist`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684916(v=VS.85).aspx) returns the depth modulo 65536, so if, for example, your depth is 65536, it'll tell you the depth is zero. Second, it only works correctly if you take special steps to align data you put into the list. Both of these can be worked around (in fact, I hesitate to mention the problem with `QueryDepthSlist`, since you should probably never call it anyway) but the alignment requirement really is *quite* annoying.

As far as how to create the other threads, since you're apparently using MFC otherwise, you pretty much *need* to use MFC to create your threads as well -- it does a few extra bits of work when you create a thread. If you're going to use MFC in a particular thread, you must let MFC create that thread. You'll probably want to use your original thread to run the GUI, and create the other threads with [`AfxBeginThread`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s3w9x78e(v=VS.80).aspx).

<sup>1</sup> Well, okay, "fatal" is overstating the situation a tiny bit, but not much. Basically, you have to use `InterlockedFlushSlist`, then traverse backward through the list of items to process them in order. Since it's a singly linked list, you can't traverse it in reverse as is. You can either do the forward traverse recursively, and do the processing on the return leg, or you can reverse the list as you traverse it. While I'm sure either *can* be made to work, you're basically fighting against the design either way.

Answer (score 0):

You've got multiple producers and one consumer?  You'll get very high performance with a minimum of effort with the Win32 [SList API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684121.aspx).  Use the PUSH and FLUSH operations in the producer and consumer, respectively.

Since you're sending messages to a GUI thread, you could also use `PostMessage`.  But if you're passing pointers through the message queue you have to worry about things like shatter attacks.  The private SList is much easier to make robust.  You can also use `PostMessage` to trigger the GUI thread to read from the SList, that's perfectly safe.

Answer (score 0):

look at www.boost.org

the code will be portable across multiple platforms and you can quickly start concentrating on service logic instead of running behind thread wrapper classes.

once you get the basics working and understand what must be possible implementation logic.. then you are better placed to write your own if you think boost is complex, and you might solve the problem on your own.

but by using of boost specifically in your case asio, i think you will be better placed to plan your design and think different aspects of threading model.

Comment: hi harishvk27, i've been reading bout boost recently but have always avoided using it because i think its too complex. But now's probably the time for me to dive in it. thanks for the tip :)

Comment: i didn't know any of the boost collections were thread safe (same with the stl), i think thats a required for the question?

Answer (score 0):

Unless the "sequence of calls" is time consuming itself, don't bother to create more threads. Your GUI already has a dedicated thread associated with it, AND a message queue.

Your GUI has a window associated with it - just use SendMessage() from the worker threads to send messages to the window on the main thread for processing and display. SendMessage will block until the GUI thread processes the message, so data pointers passed will still be in scope.

Comment: hi Chris Becke, thanks for your answer. The GUI and the sequence of calls are part of a vendor SDK. In order to update a value on the GUI, i need to look for the memory location of that specific variable allocated by the SDK and update it with a new value. This done by calling a function from the SDK. Then i need to call another function to "tell" the GUI that new values are available. I'm not able to change this sequence of events :( I was told that the functions from the SDK are not thread safe so my friend suggested that i created another thread and a queue to solve it.

Comment: Without a better description of the boundaries between MFC, the GUI, and the vendor SDK, I'm still not convinced that you need any more threads at all.